# FXML File generates GridPane default property LoadException

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, fxml

I've been having a problem building a JavaFX project using an FXML file (manually written, not generated in SceneBuilder). Below is the FXML file. This is written following the FXML instructions found at http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/fxml_tutorial.htm. The actual error that it generates is `Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: javafx.scene.layout.GridPane does not have a default property.` Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>

<Scene width = "550" 
    fx:controller = "fxmltableview.FXMLTableViewController"
    xmlns:fx = "http://javafx.com/fxml">

    <GridPane alignment = "center" hgap = "10" vgap = "10">
        <padding> <Insets top = "10" right = "10" bottom = "10" left = "10"/> </padding>
        <Label text = "Address Book" GridPane.columnIndex = "0" GridPane.rowIndex = "0" style = "-fx-font: NORMAL 20 Tahoma;"/>
        <TableView fx:id = "tableView" GridPane.columnIndex = "0" GridPane.rowIndex = "1">
            <columns> <TableColumn text = "First Name"> </TableColumn>
                      <TableColumn text = "Last Name">  </TableColumn>
                      <TableColumn text = "email">  </TableColumn>
            </columns>
        </TableView>
    </GridPane>
</Scene>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot `<children>` tag for GridPane:

```
<GridPane alignment = "center" hgap = "10" vgap = "10">
    <padding> <Insets top = "10" right = "10" bottom = "10" left = "10"/> </padding>
    <children>
      <Label text = "Address Book" GridPane.columnIndex = "0" GridPane.rowIndex = "0" style = "-fx-font: NORMAL 20 Tahoma;"/>
      <TableView fx:id = "tableView" GridPane.columnIndex = "0" GridPane.rowIndex = "1">
        <columns> <TableColumn text = "First Name"> </TableColumn>
                  <TableColumn text = "Last Name">  </TableColumn>
                  <TableColumn text = "email">  </TableColumn>
        </columns>
      </TableView>
    </children>
</GridPane>
```

Thus FXML tried to put Label and Table to `default` property which is not available for GridPane.